How to disable Auto Capitalization in new Outlook
The new Outlook (Version 1.2024.619.100, Client version 20240614008.17) incorrectly capitalizes some letters for me, for example the following:

Hallo,
das ist ein Test.

will automatically be changed to

Hallo,
Das ist ein Test.

I have not found any setting to disable this.

Why do you believe the first word of a sentence, which should be capitalized, should not be capitalized?

@Hannu - New Outlook doesn’t capitalize the first word on a line, in the author’s example, the first word of the example sentence should be capitalized.

@Hannu - Your mistaken. The example used in the question is grammatically correct. Outlook capitalization rules most certainly is based on the locale of the system.

@Ramhound Sorry, I was not aware that in English the capital 'T' is correct. However, I am using the German version and there a capital letter is incorrect. I was just translating my example because this site is English.


The new Outlook (Version 1.2024.619.100, Client version 20240614008.17) incorrectly capitalizes some letters for me

You need to disable Text predictions, Enable auto correct, and Enable auto capitalization within Microsoft Editor Settings.


On the ribbon bar left click on Select Editor > Editor Settings.

Click on the Enable auto capitalization to disable the option







Source: Autocorrect, autocapitalize, and autoformat your messages

In the old Outlook it was also possible to avoid this behavior by entering 2 newline characters after "Hallo," instead of two new paragraphs. This way, "das ist" is not seen as the beginning of a sentence but the continuation of a sentence.
You can create a newline character by pressing Shift+Enter togehter, while pressing Enter without shift creates a new paragraph.
It is the same behavior as in MS Word. There you can see if you type a newline or new paragraph character by enabling show control characters.
You could give this a try, as in most cases in German grammar it is correct to capitalize the first word of a sentence so it's also annoying when the autocorrect is switched off.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Updated it and made it clearer, hopefully.
